# How to tell if a table has been used in Postgres (9.4)

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4

I am using Postgres 9.4 and I am doing some table clean-up.

Specifically I need to do the clean-up to free up some hard disk space so I am looking at removing tables altogether that are part of old systems that are no longer needed (I will just back them up and remove them).

I know the main ones that are or are no longer needed, however I would like to see if there is a simple way to see the statistics of a table for the following:

- The last time an INSERT was performed
- The last time a SELECT was performed
- The last time an UPDATE was performed

Is there a simple way to see this?

Comment: As not strictly a programming question, this may be a better fit on [dba.se].

Comment: [pg_stat_all_tables](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/monitoring-stats.html#pg-stat-all-tables-view)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thanks - I am aware of this however it doesn't necessarily tell me the **date** of the last UPDATE, SELECT or INSERT. Is there any way I can see this from this system view?

Comment: You could reset those stats every morning

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name #genius. Thank you.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Might be a good idea to give a proper answer and I can mark it correct. I would think somebody else would have had the same problem at some point in the past or will in the future